# Install nvidia drivers without secure boot

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, python

I want to install nvidia drivers in my server which is Ubuntu, but my server does't support secure boot. I can't find secure boot item in my BIOS interface. And I can't install the drivers.

I install the drivers by `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-415`. It shows like

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-20-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda12
I: (UUID=d42cdc5e-7ede-4a3b-b613-5cf71fdf1e4b)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-20-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-415
 nvidia-driver-415
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I run `nvidia-smi`, and it show

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I want use pytorch with gpu. When I import pytorch in python, and it shows

```
>>>import torch
>>>x = torch.Tensor([1])
>>>x
tensor([1.])
>>>x.to('cuda')
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653114079/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=51 error=38 : no CUDA-capable device is detected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hekai/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 163, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (38) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653114079/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:51
```

So how can I install nvidia drivers successfully?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secure Boot has nothing to do with your issue, which is indicated by this in your command output:

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
```

Your `/boot` mount appears to be out of disk space.  You can confirm this by running `df -hT`, which shows you the free space of each file system.

To free up space in `/boot`, you should remove old kernels.  See [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/254585/18979) on Ask Ubuntu for further guidance.

After you have enough disk space in `/boot`, you should be able to install the NVIDIA proprietary driver.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps. After removing old kernels, I install drivers successfully.